# Thoughts about recovery MBP that has 2 months old Time Machine copy

Tags: macbook-pro, backup, time-machine, ssd

I have an MBP late 2011 with High Sierra installed. Two disks are installed inside: an SSD with macOS and apps, and the second disk is a Macintosh HD with a home folder. The last backup of Time Machine was made about two months ago (I was in the process of moving and could not use my Time Machine server during this period). But I actively used my MBP during this time. My Mac didn't boot yesterday. I checked and saw that Drive Utility doesn't recognize my SSD. And now I’m thinking how best to restore my MBP. Can I restore system files using Time Machine and not lose user files in these 2 months? Or maybe I should install a clean OS? I would be grateful for the constructive suggestions